# T-SQL : set start of the week from named date and show week nr of the date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, datediff

I have a code that traces a number of week of the date in a period that set by parameters

```
CREATE TABLE #test 
(
    job int, 
    dateL datetime
)

INSERT INTO #test 
VALUES (1, '2021-10-04'),
       (2, '2021-10-05'),
       (3, '2021-10-11'),
       (4, '2021-10-12')

DECLARE @startdate datetime = '2021-10-05',
        @enddate datetime = '2021-12-03'

SELECT
    dateL,
    (CASE 
         WHEN t.DateL BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate 
             THEN (DATEDIFF(wk,@startDate, t.DateL)) + 1   
             ELSE -1 
     END) AS WeekNumber 
FROM
    #test t

DROP TABLE #test
```

The results of this

```
dateL                      WeekNumber
---------------------------------------
2021-10-04 00:00:00.000       -1
2021-10-05 00:00:00.000        1
2021-10-11 00:00:00.000        2
2021-10-12 00:00:00.000        2
```

But it now quite what I need, and I don't understand how to set this to start count from `@startDate`.

So it should count like:

- 05.10 - 11.10 - first week
- 12.20 - 18.10 - second week
  and so on,

So it would look like that

```
dateL                   WeekNumber
-----------------------------------
2021-10-04 00:00:00.000    -1
2021-10-05 00:00:00.000     1
2021-10-11 00:00:00.000    *1*
2021-10-12 00:00:00.000     2
```

I tried to set `@@datefirst` to

```
datepart(weekday, @startDate)
```

but it just ignores me.

Could someone may be recommend something, thanks!

Comment: Why not count (`DATEDIFF`) the number of days and divide by 7?

Comment: Hello! I don't quite understand... so I can count amount of weeks that way `(DATEDIFF(dd,@startdate,@enddate))/7 as weeknr` but what it gives me?

Comment: wooow you meant this ` t.DateL BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate THEN (((DATEDIFF(dd,@startDate, t.DateL)))/7)+1 ` and it works...some magic there! THANK YOU!